# Pandas: ValueError: unknown type str32 for string comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string-comparison, valueerror

The following code throws `ValueError: unknown type str32 for string comparison`:

```
import pandas as pd

# Loading in some bigger data from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data
# data and code file included in zip to make it easy
df = pd.read_csv("AB_NYC_2019.csv")

print(df == "x")  # throws ValueError
```

It seems that the last line of code is legitimate. What is done wrong?

Comment: Dear fellow developer coming across the same issue and visiting this page - please upvote both the question and the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related with [the bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35700) that affected `pandas` version 1.1.0 and some versions prior to 1.0.5. It has been fixed in version 1.1.3.

Therefore, to make it go away it is recommended to upgrade `pandas` to version 1.1.3.

The bug does not manifest in smaller datasets (or the ones not loaded from CSV).

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the command in the cell above:
dataset.info()

Comment: The accepted answer is available. Try to add more info to support what you have written.